# How to sort variables that are not in an array?

Tags: c++, sorting

So i have a class with five integer members

```
struct Person {
    int health;
    int sport;
    int relatioship;
    int happiness;
    int intelligence;
};
```

I want to know which one has the highest value, which one the second highest... Depending on the ranking of this 5 integers i want to assign them a job.

Comment: You can make an array or `std::vector` of `std::reference_wrapper` pointing to each variable's reference and then sort that.

Comment: To sort something, there must be a common type. You can't sort apples and oranges. The correct design is to have a common class from which all these properties inherit, and to sort that. That is why you need to have an array of a specific type.

Comment: It's not possible to do that. You have to put values in some sort of container to sort them, otherwise there's nothing to sort. It seems that you only need max value, that's much easier to do on unrelated values.

Comment: This looks somewhat like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: It is possible; he can write custom comparators for each class. It would be tedious, but possible. All he needs is a way to "compare" each object. Was in the middle of writing an answer explaining how but the question was closed, so...

Comment: You'll need to use custom *iterators*.  You can pass the iterators and a comparison function to `std::sort`.  Much easier to use a standard container.

Comment: *I want to sort them and depending on the sorting assign the person a different job.*  -- What is the sorting criteria?   That is a huge piece of information you 've left out.  Maybe what you want is to *randomly* assign jobs to different persons, and on each "run", you randomize the order and reassign?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think what it means is e.g. "Sport > others -> Footballer", "Intelligence > Relationship > others -> Teacher", "Intelligence > others > Relationship -> Scientist"

Comment: Depending on scaleable your solution should be, you might look into entity-component-system architecture. In general, you do not need an actual "entity" class when you use such, instead you have containers with values of parameters (components) a toting reference to a "virtual" entity, an ID of sorts. So yo can have sorted containers of those components. Instead of creatign class `Person` you'll create components `Health(PersonsId)`, `Sport(PersonsID)`,  etc. They have a registration function of sort which would allow to pull all components registered by person's ID when required.

Comment: WHen you assign occupation to person, they might get component "Occupation", then if one person can have only one, while you assign them all you have to do is to check if that component exist or not, and if it does, then move to next most suitable person.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a representation of each of the values, and use that choose the job.

```
enum Stat {
    Health;
    Sport;
    Relatioship;
    Happiness;
    Intelligence;
};

using Stats = std::array<Stat, 5>;
using Job = std::string;

int getStat(Person p, Stat s) {
    switch (s) {
        case Health: return p.health;
        case Sport: return p.sport;
        case Relatioship: return p.relatioship;
        case Happiness: return p.happiness;
        case Intelligence: return p.intelligence;
    }
}

Stats getStats(Person p) {
    Stats result = { Health, Sport, Relatioship, Happiness, Intelligence };
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end(), [](Stat left, Stat right) { return getStat(p, left) < getStat(p, right); });
    return result;
}

Job getJob(Person p) {
    Stats stats = getStats(p);

    if (stats == { Sport, Health, Relatioship, Happiness, Intelligence })
        return "Footballer";
    else if (stats == { Intelligence, Health, Sport, Relatioship, Happiness })
        return "Banker";
    /* 118 more entries like that */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Person {
int health;
int sport;
int relationship;
int happiness;
int intelligence;
Person(int a, int b,int c, int d, int e) 
{
    health=a;
    sport=b;
    relationship=c;
    happiness=d;
    intelligence=e;
}
};
bool compare (Person a,Person b) 
{   
    return a.health>b.health;
};

int main() {
vector<Person>v;
v.push_back(Person(1,2,3,4,5));
v.push_back(Person(2,3,4,5,6));
sort(v.begin(), v.end(),compare);
for (auto x : v) 
    cout << x.health << ", " << x.sport<<endl; 

return 0;
}
Based off highest health: 
2, 3
1, 2

 Since I don't know how your comparison works it will be similar to this.
```